# Is Struct Derefencing Valid OpenCL?

Tags: opencl

I tend to write OpenCL code like the following:

```
void do_something(float4 *thefoo)
{
    thefoo->s0++;
}

__kernel void MyKernel(__global float4 myfloat)
{
    do_something(&myfloat);
}
```

Of course, it's a toy example.  It works as expected under Nvidida's OpenCL SDK (which I have access to), but my friend/project-partner is running AMD APP SDK, and he complains that this doesn't compile.  It gives:

```
error: expression must have pointer-to-struct-or-union type
```

Using `(*thefoo).s0++` works on his system, but it makes the code very ugly.

I cannot find any mention of the `->` operator in the OpenCL spec, but I also don't think I'm violating any of the pointer restrictions.  Is what I've written valid OpenCL?

Additionally, I intend to write a lot more code using structs in the above context instead of vector types.  If this *is* a mistake on my part, am I going to encounter the same gotcha when he pulls my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `float4` is not a struct; it is a built-in vector type.

You must use the `.` operator to access components of the vector. This is why `(*thefoo).s0++` will work on all conforming OpenCL implementations while `thefoo->s0++` does not.

Refer to section `6.1.7` ("Vector Components") in the OpenCL specification for more information.

Comment: I suppose vectors are a "C extension", and therefore don't inherit any syntax from structs, unlike their application side counterparts `cl_typen` which *are* structs.  I had gotten into the habit of thinking of them as such, but clearly this is a mistake.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, which OpenCL implementation worked with `->` and which one didn't?

Comment: Nvidia accepts the syntax, AMD does not.  I don't know the exact versions of the toolkits.